LaTeX Error: File `size11.clo' not found
I have recently upgrade (via .ISO image) my Thinkpad to Ubuntu 24.04, unfortunately since then it has been mostly fixing issues. So far I managed it by myself, but this latex problem is causing me a bit of stress and since I did not able to find any proper fix even after giving it a few tries. I hope to seek some proper advice here.
Info about my system [1], the details of installing TexLive is given here [2], all the local styles files are kept in /home/USER-NAME/texmf/tex/latex/local
The snippet of my resume file (main_de.tex) is here [3]. The result of running the code that produce this error LaTeX Error: File size11.clo not found. is here [4]. Also kpsewhich command has none output:
$ kpsewhich size11.clo                         
$


If any other information is needed, please do let me know. I really appreciate any input in proper direction.
Best Regards,
[1]
Linux xxxx-xxxx-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga-Gen-4 6.8.0-1016-oem #16-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct 16 09:50:49 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[2]

I got the repository and the Texlive packageinstall-tl-20241114 via official website and did manual installation via

sudo perl ./install-tl --no-interaction


The path set in the .zshrc are following

# Latex
export TEXMFHOME="/home/USER-NAME/texmf"
export TEXINPUTS="/home/USER-NAME/texmf//:."
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
export TEXHOME="/home/USER-NAME/texmf"

Also,
$ echo $PATH  
/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

The version:
$ tlmgr --version                                                                  
tlmgr revision 71331 (2024-05-24 09:30:36 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2024
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2024

[3]
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}
\usepackage{expl3}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3regex.sty\endcsname{} 

% snippet von moderncvstyleclassic.sty
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {
      \bfseries#3}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}% 
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
     \strut%
      \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}
     }
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ifsym}
%\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=20mm, right=20mm, top=18.5mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry}


%% Top Content
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.7cm} 
\firstname{xxxx}
\familyname{xxxx}
\title{Lebenslauf}

%%% FOOTER
\address{\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{./Bilders/icons/Home_icon_grey} xxxx xxxx xx}{xxxx xxxx}
\mobile{
      \includegraphics[width=0.28cm]{./Bilders/icons/phone2} +xx xxx xxxxx \hspace{0.1cm} $\circ$ \hspace{0.1cm}  
      \includegraphics[width=0.28cm]{./Bilders/icons/email2} xxxxxx@xxxx.com
      }
\photo[130pt][1.9pt]{./Bilders/bewerbung/new_supersmall.jpg}         


%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\setlength{\footskip}{46pt}
\begin{document}
-----
-----
-----
-----
\end{document}

[4]
$ latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape" -f -use-make -verbose lebenslauf/Latex/main_de.tex  
Rc files read:
  /etc/LatexMk
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Apr. 2024. Version 4.85.
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'size11.clo' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "size11.clo"'
------------
make: *** No rule to make target 'size11.clo'.  Stop.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  lebenslauf/Latex/main_de.tex
Category 'changed_user':
  lebenslauf/Latex/main_de.tex

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape  -recorder  "lebenslauf/Latex/main_de.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lebenslauf/Latex/main_de.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(/home/USER-NAME/texmf/tex/latex/local/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class

! LaTeX Error: File `size11.clo' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: clo)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.66 \input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
                              ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main_de.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_de.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_de.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_de.log'
Latexmk: Missing input file 'size11.clo' (or dependence on it) from following:
  ! LaTeX Error: File `size11.clo' not found.
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'size11.clo' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "size11.clo"'
------------
make: *** No rule to make target 'size11.clo'.  Stop.
Failure to make 'main_de.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main_de.log' and/or above output for details



Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I know you should better use 10pt for your Cv with class moderncv. For me it seems your installation is incomplete, but I have no experience with ubuntu...

@Mensch I have the same feeling that its incomplete, but that's the same recipe I followed for older version of Ubuntu. And really don't know how to get it right!

export TEXINPUTS="/home/USER-NAME/texmf//:."  removes all the standard search paths, don't do that. That is whty TeX can not find size11.cl0
In 99.9999% of cases you should only set the PATH but if you do set these tex environment variables make sure you include the standard paths, make thenm end in : but it is usually better not to set them.

I tried keeping 1. both, as mentioned above and then 2. I tried keeping just PATH 3. keeping only export TEXINPUTS="/home/USER-NAME/texmf//:.". In every case, I receive the same error. Also kpsewhich size11.clo returns null every time.

If you set TEXINPUTS to that value it can not work, it is explicitly preventing trx from searching the standard places @Violet

@Violet check you have the files and tex isn't finding them (rather than the files being missing) your pdflatex should be /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex and size11.clo should be /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo

yes David, you are right about both   1. pdflatx is this one: /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex  2.  this exist '/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo'

@Violet so don't set TEXINPUTS to exclude /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist  So the  simplest way is not to set it at all. Also check that which pdflatex does get that pdflatex not an ubuntu system tex under /bin

Yeah it is the right pdflatex which pdflatex                                                                                         /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex  Alright, it is starting to make sense. As per as your recommendation, I just set ```export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"


yes just setting PATH should work, test first on the commandline, if you run tex from a graphical editor you need to make sure you set PATH in the shell that controls the desktop your personal .bashrc/.zshrc may be too late,it depends how things are set up and how you start the editor

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @David, I really appreciate taking out your time to help me fixing this issue. If that's alright with you, I have taken this conversation to Chat , since pasting code etc is much comfortable there. So far everything you said was correct, however it still did not fix the core issue :(

there's no-one there:-)

Finally the issue has been sorted out. A bit thanks to @David and @Canageek!
Here is the summary of main issues:

PATHs were wrongly defined
In my several tries of fixing texlive, I installed some packages in ~/texmf which were interfering during compilation
also latexmk was installed via distro package so was causing the trouble.

